# CRYFS - I get issues, do people still use?

Tags: encryption, cryfs

I have been using cryfs and it seems to work, ok-ish.  I frequently get this message after trying to unlock an encrypted folder.

"Deriving encryption key (this can take some time)...Killed"
Have other users of cryfs ran into this issue?  I have researched that this may be solved by deleting the /.local/share/cryfs, however this doesnt seem to be a fix as this error message is present frequently and fixed by a reboot. However I feel that deleting a folder, or rebooting daily seems to be a viable solution.

If I reboot, I can get in. If I search for possible solutions, I don't see much offered, especially recent info, which leads me to wonder if this is still a viable solution to have an encrypted folder. I use it locally and backup to a nas .  I could use encfs, but that is stated as unsecured.

Thoughts to this issue, or should I be using a different solution to keep encrypted files in a folder?

System Details:
CryFS Version 0.10.2
ubuntu 22.04

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; and your question as written does not include an actual clear problem to be solved (see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) thus would be better suited (*as written in my opinion*) on a forum instead of a Q&A site like this. Currently I see nothing on-topic for this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: True, ( edited with additional details ) the question about the error may be better to be asked on the cryfs github. Regards

Comment: fyi: https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share my findings that have corrected my issue.

Issue - when I would have a high amount of Memory used, I would get an error - 'Killed' when trying to unlock cryfs.

```
example:  I have 16GB of RAM, 1.5GB is reserved for graphics.  If I had many applications open and would be using about 10GB of RAM I would experience the issue. Post reboot, I did not have as many applications open, hence it would work.  For reference, the encrypted folder is approx 30GB.
```

The developer of cryfs stated "Processes can get killed either by other processes or by the operating system when resources get scarce. Assuming you don't have anything installed that kills other processes and you're not killing it manually, that leaves the operating system. The most common resource to get scarce is memory"

I have upgraded my memory, and I have not had a recurrence of the issue. The other option is to try to close unnecessary applications and test again. Given that the developer was responsive, I would call this an active and maintained application.

Regards,